# Practical usage of XML?

Tags: html, xml

In my journey with computers I just started basics of web. After a nice practice on HTML now I am facing XML.

I can understand all the concepts about XML as a language and I understand that it is used to deal with data and not just rendering a webpage.

What I cannot get is when and how you use XML on the web. Webpages are written in HTML, so I wonder, when the XML shows up? Can anybody provide few practical examples? When do you want to write an XML file and where do you put it? Can a webpage be a mixture of HTML and XML?

I am sorry for this naive and very basic question but for some reasons my brain refuses to digest this thing.

Thanks

Comment: @HaukurKristinsson That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML stores data and that's all. XSL takes that data, matches patterns and produces (usually) HTML.

It is possible, in theory, to download an XML file (or any data in XML format) with an attached stylesheet and render it entirely on the client but that would not do much for the page's search engine ranking.

What usually happens is the HTML file uses javascript to download the XML data, render it with either XSL or javascript and then modify the HTML on the page. This means you don't have to refresh the entire page or download superfluous formatting data with every request.

Comment: So the "XML" file (the data) is different file than my l .html file of my web page. The javascript gets the data from the XML and renders the page with the data from the XML file. Did I get it right? Maybe I made it too simple and generic but it's just to get the right idea.

Comment: Usually, you will have a destination div (eg ID='destination'), use ajax or XMLHttpRequest to download the XML data, use XSLTProcessor to convert to HTML and set the destination's innerHTML to the result.
Beware importing nodes - in some implementations (*cough* Microsoft), a browser's tag is not the same as XSLT's tag, they just happen to share the same name.
You can do this over and over again without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a markup language for encoding information that is easily readable by humans and easily parsed by computers. It's commonly used for communicating with/to Web APIs for example.

You can read more about it on w3.org on https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/.

Answer (score 0):

As others says XML is markup language ant it's mostly used to transfer some data. For example all web services which run on SOAP protocol uses XML for storing it's inforamtion and so on. And yes, in some way XHTML is mixture of HTML and XML. it's have more strictly rules for example all elements must always be closed but it not so much different than ordinary HTML.

You could read more in there http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp